# Android download project from code.google.com

Tags: android, svn

I know it may be simple or stupid question but i can`t find an answer.

How I download the whole project from:
http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/org/broncho/pdfreader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need svn installed. Then use from command line

```
svn checkout http://android-pdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-pdf-read-only
```

Or follow guidelines at http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/source/checkout if you for example use subversion plugins to eclipse or which IDE you are using.

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked to contains another link with checkout instructions: http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/source/checkout

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the listed proposition http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html
or tortoise (gui) tool for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install any SVN Software for example TortoiseSVN (download it from http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)